# JSON key to string or variable passed to id's

Tags: jquery, json, string

How do I convert JSON key into string or variable.

JSON:

```
"uk": {
        "navigation": ["apple", "pear", "lemon"],
        "carousel":{
            "fruit":["dummyFruit1", "dummyFruit2"],
            "salad":["dummySalad1", "dummySalad2"]
        }
    }
```

so that the HTML would like like this:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div id="fruit">
       <p>dummyFruit1></p>
       <p>dummyFruit2></p>
    </div>
    <div id="salad">
       <p>dummySalad1></p>
       <p>dummySalad2></p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

so the keys would be passed to the div id's

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What did you tired so far?

Comment: Get it like **eg:var value = uk.navigation[0]**

Comment: @RaghuChandra that is returning an array element, not an object key

Comment: @charlietfl -  I agree, I need this to be a string

Comment: Ohh i dint understand the question properly! what would you say about **var key = uk[0];**

Comment: use `for(key in object)` or `$.each(obj, function(key,value){..})`

Comment: @RaghuChandra I'd say `uk` isn't an array so that's meaningless.

Comment: Okay Thanks! i understood after charlietfl comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
var myJson = {"uk": {
    "navigation": ["apple", "pear", "lemon"],
    "carousel":{
        "fruit":["dummyFruit1", "dummyFruit2"],
        "salad":["dummySalad1", "dummySalad2"]
    }
}};

$(function(){
var myHtml = "<div id='carousel'>";
$.each(myJson.uk.carousel,function(k,v){
    myHtml += "<div id='" + k + "'>";
    myHtml += "<p>" + v[0] + "</p>";
    myHtml += "<p>" + v[1] + "</p>";
    myHtml += "</div>";
});
myHtml += "</div>";
$("#test").html(myHtml);
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/zgwh4qpp/